# Is 1MB = 1000000 bytes OR 1048576 considering file size

Tags: asp.net, file, size

I have to place a 1MB size check on my files to be uploaded . Now in code (using c#) i have to mention the size in bytes . Should i check the size of upload file  with the value 
MaxSizeInBytes = 1048576 OR MaxSizeInBytes = 1000000 .

Comment: It depends on your requirements and the interpretation of a megabyte :)

Comment: Are you a hard disk vendor or RAM maker? They like to count low.

Answer (score 0):

In most operating systems, files of 1048576 bytes will show as "1 MB" (and more importantly, files of 1000000 bytes will show as "less than 1MB"). So the user will have the expectation to be able to upload such a file if the form says it accepts "1 MB files".